# (TCP client programming in python)how to make my hex string in regular expression correctly after i get it by using recv()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a TCP client app to receive some data from a local server and it works.

here's  all the code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = '192.168.1.10'
port = 4001

s.connect((host,port))
print('')
print('********************************************************')
print (s.recv(13))
print('********************************************************')
s.close
```

I run it in dos and it shows the data I want

[image]

BUT what i really need is those in the **red rectangle**

so i changed my code a little bit,but it doesn't show what i want. i guess i just mess up all the regular expression

here's my python code,it's pretty simple

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket
import re

s = socket.socket()
host = '192.168.1.10'
port = 4001

s.connect((host,port))
print(' ')
print('********************************************************')
#print (s.recv(13))
#m = re.match(r'^\xn[5-12]',s.recv(13))
a = s.recv(13)
m = re.match(r'^/\xn[5-12]$',a)
print(m)
print('********************************************************')
s.close
```

Comment: What should the correct regex match, in plain English?

Comment: The value you get back from `recv` is a `bytes` object. It doesn't literally contain characters like `\x00`: those are just a string representation used for printing. The `bytes` object holds the actual bytes like `08 00 00 00` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Take a slice of the bytes: `a[4:7]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the numerical value from the bytes
object, you have to take those values individually.

```
redRectangle = [a[i] for i in range(4,7)]
```